# Saving and Displaying Image from database using MySQL workbench

Tags: java, mysql, database

Good day, I was trying to test on uploading an image to my database but when i'm trying to retrieve the image, nothing shows..

Here's my code for uploading the image

```
String m_dataForImage;
public String getDataForImage() { return m_dataForImage; }
public void setDataForImage(String value) { this.m_dataForImage = value; }


String m_ShowPhoto;
public String getShowPhoto() { return m_ShowPhoto; }
public void setShowPhoto(String value) { this.m_ShowPhoto = value; }

String m_fileName;
public String getFileName() { return m_fileName; }
public void setFileName(String value) { this.m_fileName = value; }

public void onUploadFile(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent event) {
    if (event instanceof BaseActionEventUpload){
        try{
            ConnectionPool.getInstance();
            Base.open(ConnectionPool.dataSourcePooled);

            BaseActionEventUpload bae =(BaseActionEventUpload)event;
            setFileName(bae.getClientFileName());
            m_ShowPhoto = bae.getHexByteString();
            byte[] imageByte = bae.getHexBytes();
            setShowPhoto("/hex("+ValueManager.encodeHexString(imageByte)+")");//trying to convert byte to hex

            photo_storage photo = new photo_storage();
                photo.set("timestamp","ss");
                photo.set("Primary_Key", "123");
                photo.set("File_Name",getFileName());
                photo.set("Image_Data",getShowPhoto());

            photo.saveIt();



        }catch(Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
            Statusbar.outputAlert(t.toString());
        }finally {
            Base.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and for showing the image:

```
public void onShowImage(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent event) {
        try{
            ConnectionPool.getInstance();
            Base.open(ConnectionPool.dataSourcePooled);

            List<photo_storage> photo = photo_storage.where("Primary_Key = ?",123);
            for (photo_storage so:photo){ setShowPhoto("/hex("+ValueManager.encodeHexString(so.getBytes("Image_Data"))+")");
                setFileName(so.getString("File_Name"));
                setDataForImage(so.getString("Image_Data"));

        }catch(Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
            Statusbar.outputAlert(t.toString());
        }finally {
            Base.close();
        }
}
```

Im currently using Intellij and CaptainCasa..

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it should be

```
    photo.set("Image_Data",imageByte);
```

instead of

```
    photo.set("Image_Data",getShowPhoto());
```

because imageByte is where the uploaded image stored.